# how to play a sound on click of button

Tags: android

i am trying to play sound file on the emulator on click of button but i am getting message "application play audio has stopped unexpectedly"

my codes are:

```
package com.java4u.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public  class p1 extends Activity {


// creating instance of media player
MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.meow);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btnSound=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.playSound);

    btnSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.java4u.android.p1")); 
            mp.start();
        }
    }); 

        }

}
```

---

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.java4u.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".p1" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:text="play audio" 
    android:id="@+id/playSound" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: accept the answer whichever helped you so that it would be helpful to others and also would increase your reputation. @akash gupta

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xBtn1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.fruit_dance);  
        mp1.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the creation of the `MediaPlayer` instance to the `onCreate` method.
This will make your application run:

```
// creating instance of media player
MediaPlayer mp; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ljudman__grenade);
```

Also, if you're trying to start a new instance of your activity upon the button click I believe this is the correct way to do it:

```
startActivity(new Intent(p1.this, p1.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

`mp.start()` should be before starting a new activity.

```
      btnSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
            startActivity(new Intent(currentActivityName.this, newActivityName.class)); 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //inside toggle button 
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.sound);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme);
    if(toggleButton.isChecked())
        mp.start();
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!toggleButton.isChecked()){
                mp.pause();
            }
            else {
                mp.start();
                mp.isLooping();
            }
        }
    });
```