# How to give unique background sounds to different buttons on soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to provide background sounds? When i click on space button it should provide different sound, when i click on numbers it should give different click sound. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, maybe you could override keysPressed and play the sounds

something like:

```
    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || ...) .....
```

Or another option is creating a custom keyboard of your own.

Edit 1:  You can play the sound with the following code:

```
    final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.fruit_dance);  
    mp1.start();
```

[how to play a sound on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394422/how-to-play-a-sound-on-click-of-button)

Comment: Yes am creating my own custom keyboard. But not able to add sounds :(

Comment: Am adding below code                                                    final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);          mp1.start();