# make click sound when pressing a button

Tags: android

Where should I add the button.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK); ?
Should it be here:

```
    //onClick event where myButton1 is pressed a click sound occurs
    public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.b_Press1){
            myButton1.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394422/how-to-play-a-sound-on-click-of-button

Comment: have add button on setOnClickListner();

Answer (score 1):

1) You should put mp3 file in /raw folder.

2) Put this code inside onCreate() method after setContentView()

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {  
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        } 
        try {

            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

3.Sound will be played again each time you press button. You don't have to write any extra code for that.

Note that AudioFile.mp3 is the name of the mp3 file in /raw folder

Hope this answer is helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

try it out

```
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
     Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {  
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        } 
        try {

            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd("song.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The sound effect will only be played if sound effects are enabled by the user, and isSoundEffectsEnabled() is true.

so make sure you enable it using xml like

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
```

or

through code

```
myButton1.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code. for more information read this [link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants.html)   and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905651/playing-sound-effect-click-navigation-right-for-button-clicks-android)

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                button.playSoundEffect(0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `playSoundEffect()` for clicks yourself. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29):

> The framework will play sound effects for some built in actions, such as clicking

Also note:

> The sound effect will only be played if sound effects are enabled by the user